# Working with array loop

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have this array on a foreach loop:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Txt_OrigemPath.Text);
reader.ReadLine().Skip(1);
string conteudo = reader.ReadLine();            
string[] teste = conteudo.Split(new[] { '*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string s in teste)
{
    string oi = s;
}
```

The line i'm reading contains a few fields like `matriculation, id, id_dependent, birthday ...`
I have a CheckedListBox where the user selects wich fields he wants to select and what order he wants, according to this selection and knowing the order of each value in the array like(I know the first is `matriculation`the second is `id` and the third is `name`), how could I select some of the fields, pass it's value to some variable and order them according to the checkedlistbox's order ? Hope I could be clear.

I tried this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Txt_OrigemPath.Text))
            {
                var campos = new List<Campos>();
                reader.ReadLine();
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string conteudo = reader.ReadLine();
                    string[] array = conteudo.Split(new[] { '*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    var campo = new Campos
                    {
                        numero_carteira = array[0]
                    };
                    campos.Add(campo);
                }
            }
```

Now How may I run over the list and compare its values with those fields selected by the user from the  `checkedlistbox` ?
Because if I instance the class again out the `{}` it's values will be empty...

```
Person p = new Person();
string hi = p.numero_carteira;  // null.....
```

Comment: What do you think `reader.ReadLine().Skip(1);` does? Because it does bugger all.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish in the first place?

Comment: nope, not clear at all. I get that you want to display items from file, and that you have a checkedlistbox to select and order the items. Since you have the items in a list, you just need to compare the items in the list with the items in the checkedlistbox and create a new list with the items select in the correct order, then put that data into whatever your output is (ListView?)

Comment: @Antonie - hopefully that's a typo, but either way, he's reading and discarding the first line in each file.

Comment: @DavidHope not in each file... It just skip the first line of the file... And How would I compare these? I tried but couldnt make it =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Skip(1)` will skip the first character of the string of first line returned by `reader.ReadLine()`. Since `reader.ReadLine()` by itself skips the first line, `Skip(1)` is completely superfluous.

First create a class which can store your fields

```
public class Person
{
    public string Matriculation { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string IDDependent { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1} ({2})", ID, Matriculation, Birthday);
    }
}
```

(Here I used strings for simplicity, but you could use ints and DateTimes as well, which requires some conversions.)

Now, create a list where the persons will be stored

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
```

Add the entries to this list. Do **not** remove empty entries when splitting the string, because otherwise you will lose the position of your fields!

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Txt_OrigemPath.Text)) {
    reader.ReadLine();  // Skip first line (if this is what you want to do).
    while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
        string conteudo = reader.ReadLine();
        string[] teste = conteudo.Split('*');
        var person = new Person {
            Matriculation = teste[0],
            ID = teste[1],
            IDDependent = teste[2],
            Birthday = teste[3]
        };
        persons.Add(person);
    }
}
```

The `using` statement ensures that the `StreamReader` is closed when finished.

Comment: @OliverJacot-Descombes I dont want to remove empty entries, because if I the empty entry is some field the user wants, i'll replace the `""` for something else, you know ? I'll try it now

Comment: Oliver it says `invalid expression term 'string` why ?

Comment: @Ghaleon: I typed code the directly into StackOverflow answer box without testing it in Visual Studio. In Visual Studio I found two errors. #1: One missing ")" at the end of the `using` line. #2: It should not read `string[xy]` but `teste[xy]` in `Matriculation = teste[0]` and so on. Fixed the answer. You used the string split option `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`; therefore I said that you wanted to remove empty entries.

Comment: Yes, thanks... One last thing, how could I order them to write on the streamwriter.writeline(); ? I need to compare these fields with those that were selected by the user from the CheckedListBox. Because if I instance the class person again the values will be empty

Comment: If you override the `ToString` method of the `Person` class (see my edit above) to return what you want to display in your `CheckedListBox`, you can add all the persons to the `CheckedListBox` by simply setting its `DataSource` property to the persons list: `myCheckedListBox.DataSource = persons;`. Now you can get the actual person with: `Person p = (Person)myCheckedListBox.SelectedItem;`. Or `if (myCheckedListBox.GetItemChecked(i)) { Person p = (Person)myCheckedListBox.Items[i]; }`